# Tensorflow implementation of Andrew Ng's cat vs non cat example (coursera)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

After completing a basic machine learning course I tried to reproduce one of the examples using TensorFlow as practice. In the original example the Neural Network is made from scratch, I would like to reproduce the same Neural Network with TensorFlow.
I was able to create the same layer structure and activation functions, but the results are different.
Using the original code the cost decreases much slower e.g.:

- after 100 epoch: original code: 0.67..., TensorFlow: 0.50...
- after 400 epoch: original code: 0.57..., TensorFlow: 0.27...

I know it is better, but I would like to understand the reason of the difference.

My code:

```
    tf.random.set_seed(1)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(20, activation = "relu"),
    layers.Dense(7, activation = "relu"),
    layers.Dense(5, activation = "relu"),
    layers.Dense(1, activation = "sigmoid")
])

model.compile(
    loss = keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits = False),
    optimizer = keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate = 0.0075),
    metrics = ["accuracy"]
)
model.fit(train_x, train_y, batch_size = 209, epochs = 500, verbose = 2) #batch_size = 209 = number of train examples, to have batch gradient descent
```

Original code and dataset is available here: https://github.com/ridhimagarg/Cat-vs-Non-cat-Deep-learning-implementation

Course: "Neural Networks and Deep Learning" by Andrew Ng,
Example: cat vs non cat classifier with 4 layer NN.

I use the same:

- number of layers and nodes
- loss/cost (the terminology is a little bit confusing): BinaryCrossentropy
- gradient descent without momentum (SGD)
- learning rate (0.0075)
- batch gradient descent (batch_size = number of train examples)
- random seed

Any ideas?
Maybe the difference is in the weight initialization? If yes, than how can I modify that?
Any help appreciated, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The weights/bias initialization is the reason.
This is the original initialization:

```
    W1 = np.random.randn(n_h, n_x) *0.01
    b1 = np.zeros((n_h, 1))
    W2 = np.random.randn(n_y, n_h) *0.01
    b2 = np.zeros((n_y, 1))
```

You could implement your own initializer in Keras and pass to your model.

[Keras initializer](https://keras.io/api/layers/initializers/)

To replicate the same initialization in tensorflow:

```
def my_init(shape, dtype=None):
     np.random.seed(1)
     a = np.random.randn(shape[0], shape[1])*0.01  # the same initialization as in the original code from coursera
     return tf.convert_to_tensor(a, dtype = dtype) # converting the output to a tensor
```

Add my_init to the layers, e.g.:

```
layers.Dense(20, activation = "relu", kernel_initializer = my_init),
```